# Changing style of a class in php

Tags: php, html

I have a link with a class and I want to change the style of that class using php. The only solution I could come up with was to echo a  statement but I'd rather not do that if it is avoidable. Is there a better way to do this?

```
if ($page_number)
{
    echo "<style type='text/css'>
        .pagination a:nth-child(".$page_number.") {
            display:inline-block;
            padding: 0 3px;
            border: #AAAAEE thin solid;
            background-color: #2266BB;
            color: #ffffff !important; 
            cursor:default;
        }
    </style>";
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the style with PHP rather than Javascript or just CSS? I mean, is there something specific about `condition` that it has to be evaluated on the server?

Comment: The correct way is to make an additional class with the CSS that change, but in CSS, not in PHP. It's absurd non-sense

Comment: The condition will change and so will the number. I need to do it with php to target the correct element under the parent.

Comment: You should probably be using PHP to add a class to the HTML, not an entire stylesheet.

Comment: Outline the objective, and we may be able to assist rethinking your approach...

Comment: I have a number of links that display the pagination of a blog. I can't change the html but can add in php. I want to check that the page is the blog page which is where the condition comes in and then change the colour of the current page which is the number.
I'd like to remove the link but I can't seem to find out how to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have a class pre-designed in your CSS for the current page, like so:

```
.currenPage {
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0 3px;
        border: #AAAAEE thin solid;
        background-color: #2266BB;
        color: #ffffff !important; 
        cursor:default;
    }
```

and you'll add this class to the element with either javascript or PHP (i recommend js)

PHP:

```
$class="";
if(//page is current){
    $class="currentPage";
}
echo("<li><a href='#' class=".$class.">Page N</a></li>");
```

JS:

```
var currentPageLinkEl = document.getElementById("pageNlink");
currentPageEl.className += "currentPage";
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is a better way

```
<li class="pagination <?php if(condition){ echo 'current_page'; } ?>">1</li>
<li class="pagination <?php if(condition){ echo 'current_page'; } ?>">1</li>
<li class="pagination <?php if(condition){ echo 'current_page'; } ?>">1</li>
```

You should already have styled this in your css file

```
.current_page{
 padding: 0 3px;
            border: #AAAAEE thin solid;
            background-color: #2266BB;
            color: #ffffff !important; 
            cursor:default;
}
```

The style is automatically applied to the link that meets the condition
I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I can't actually get the code into the HTML which is why I'm trying to it by php. I don't have access to the HTML which is why I'm trying to do it seperately.
If you could change the HTML I would have done it this way already.